# Azure APIM custom connector returns empty body response in Power Apps

Tags: azure-api-management, powerapps, power-platform

I’m going through the wizard to create a custom connector in Power Apps to call a simple Get operation in Azure APIM. I can call the API fine using Postman, Fiddler and CURL. However, when I try to test the connector using the test tab I’m getting a 200 OK but the response body is empty:
[image]

It’s worth mentioning that this issue, with empty response body, occurs only for APIs in Azure APIM. If I hit the backend API, hosted in Azure App Service, without going through Azure APIM I’m receiving a response body. I have tested with other public APIs on the internet which works fine as well. The problem with empty response seems to have something to do with the integration between Power Apps and Azure APIM.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you import a JSON "Response" in the Custom Connector?

Comment: @SeaDude as already described in my question, I'm able to call any other API and test sucessfully. Further, calling the backend API directly (without going through APIM) works fine. I don't think this has anything to do with importing a JSON response, which by the way I have tried already.

Comment: I understand that you use curl, fiddler, postman, etc. But its unclear whether you clicked on "Response" under the "Definition" tab in the Custom Connector, then "Import from sample". In there, paste the JSON  from one of the other tools.

Comment: @SeaDude what I'm trying to explain it that all other APIs that I'm testing from the custom connector are working fine, i.e they return a response. I don't need to import any JSON sample for those, why would I need on for the response that is coming back from APIM? In any case I have tried importing a JSON response schema as well, which still doe not work in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Azure Application Insights logs, I discovered that this is ralated to CORS. To resolve the issue, I added the https://flow.microsoft.com to Azure APIM CORS policy to allow calls from the PowerApps test console to come through, like so:

[image]